# signal r mvc 4 display details on index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I tried to display signal r some text using mvc 4 index view. i didn't get any msg on index page.

Hub code

```
 public class TasksHub : Hub
{
    public void NewTaskDetails(int taskid,string taskname,string created,string role)
    {
        Clients.All.addMessage(taskid, taskname, created, role);
 } }
```

controller

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TaskManager.Hubs.TasksHub>();
context.Clients.All.addMessage
(tasklist.Taskid,tasklist.Taskname,tasklist.createdby,tasklist.Role);
```

view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-alpha1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/SignalR/Hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var THub = $.connection.TaskHub;
    $messages = $("#messages");
    myHub.client.send = function (taskid, taskname, created, role) {
        $messages.append("<br /><b>" + taskid + ":</b>" + taskname);
    }

    $.connection.hub.start();
});



</script>
<div id="messages">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off your line:

```
 myHub.client.send = function (taskid, taskname, created, role) {
    $messages.append("<br /><b>" + taskid + ":</b>" + taskname);
}
```

needs to be:

```
 THub.client.send = function (taskid, taskname, created, role) {
    $messages.append("<br /><b>" + taskid + ":</b>" + taskname);
}
```

What is myHub you didn't declare that variable?

2nd in the lines above you defined a function that the Hub can call to send the message to the client. You called that function "send" but on the hub side you are calling "addMessage"

3rd you need to define some client action that will execute the hub method call. I mean what triggers the invocation of the hub method? You need to add some logic to your $.connection.hub.start() something like:

```
 $('#someElement').click(function () {
    // Declare taskid, taskname, created, role.
    THub.server.NewTaskDetails(taskid, taskname, created, role);
 }
```

Comment: i change my code but still i got error                         Unhandled exception at line 65, column 9 in http://localhost:45845/

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'TasksHub' of undefined or null reference                               '  $(document).ready(function ()
    {   var THub = $.connection.TasksHub;
        $messages = $("#messages");
        THub.client.send = function (taskid, taskname, created, role) { $messages.append("<br /><b>" + taskid + ":</b>" + taskname);
        }  $.connection.THub.start();});

Comment: Can you update the code from your question to what you have right now? Also SignalR is now officially released, you should download and use the latest version via NuGet instead of the alpha version you are using now. 

Also have you added the RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); as the first line in your global.asax file?

Lastly try putting a hubname attribute on your Hub Class. So basically put [HubName("TasksHub")] on your hub class and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: If you still have issues take a look at this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4